# Issue while installing graylog-web

Tags: linux, centos, yum, graylog2

While installing graylog2-web application with yum, I faced the below issue

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: graylog-server conflicts with graylog2-web-0.20.6-4.noarch
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to mix graylog 1 with graylog 2. You probably need to keep a consistent version installed.

Comment: I've installed graylog2 also
yum install graylog2-server

Comment: Then you need to uninstall graylog-server and the other graylog 1 installs that are conflicting with your graylog 2 installs.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one it will be solved

Step 1:

```
$ sudo yum clean all
```

Step 2:

```
$ sudo yum install graylog2-web --skip-broken
```

Comment: It didn't work :( 
--> Processing Conflict: graylog-server-2.2.0-2.alpha.4.noarch conflicts graylog2-web

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    graylog2-web-0.20.6-4.noarch from graylog2
    1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.121-2.6.8.1.el6_8.x86_64 from updates
    lksctp-tools-1.0.10-7.el6.x86_64 from base